# What does the "best" number on stage select mean?

Tags: kirby-and-the-forgotten-land

When selecting a stage on the overworld, the stage preview screen has a "best" number just above the mission list.

What does this "best" number mean? Is it my best score? Best level time?

[image: Best 301]

Comment: Can't check until tonight when my kid gets home, but my first thought is star coins received?

Comment: @Joe Looks like you're right, [it is star coins collected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDbPW.jpg). Interestingly, it seems to include the bonus star coins received for replaying a level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As Joe suggested](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/396516/what-does-the-best-number-on-stage-select-mean#comment556807_396516), the "best" record is for how many star coins you collected during a level. Interestingly, this includes the bonus star coins that replace caged Waddle Dees when replaying a level.

[image: New "best" record]